# What is difference between these two code snippets?

Tags: java, for-loop, random, compiler-errors, difference

Below are two codes which first one is compiling and result is infinity loop, but with another one I get a compiler error as "Not a statement". As `Math.random()` returns `double` between 0.0 and 1.0 it is very strange for me why both of them do not gives same result.

**1st**

```
    for(;;Math.random()){
        System.out.println("Infinity Loop");
    }
```

**2nd**

```
    double i = 0.12654;
    for(;;i){
      System.out.println("Compile error");
    }
```

Comment: The problem with the 2nd one is that the third argument of the for loop can't be a variable I would guess. It should work if you write `for(;;i++){}` for example.

Comment: Your question boils down to: (why) is `i` (not) a statement?

Comment: Or rather what the difference between a statement and an expression is.

Comment: @Laisender but Math.random() also returns us a variable but it is ok, it is working

Comment: Math.random() is however a statement. Even if it returns a plain old number.

Comment: @luk2302 let me express myself again. If Math.random() returns us [double] like [i] (for example 0.12654). Why this 2 statement not working as same. What is difference? both of them are double. But 1 of them is compiling another not. Why? Generally..

Comment: Because one calls a function that returns something and the other just is something, that is a fundamental difference.

Comment: @Laisender ok +1. Ok I understood thank you for this information. But can you explain me please this logic in this situation? Why it should be infinity loop when we put [Math.random()] in third argument? How this happens?

Comment: That is a different question and does not relate to the last statement but is based on when the middle statement evaluates to false causing the loop to stop.

Comment: For loop goes like this: `for(inital, whenToAbort, increment)` . When you don't say when to abort its not going to abort.

Comment: Thank you for these information. I understood part of them. Actually I know how `for` loop works. But now I want to know why `Math.random()` is not giving compiling error. Ok this is statement what `for` needs. But its not increment (or decrement... etc.). Maybe I need to open new question for this. Because this is another topic.

Answer (score 1):

The for loop requires three statements separated by semi-colons (or, as you illustrate, you can have no statement).

Java supports three types of statements:

1. Expression statements - those that create objects, call methods or change variables (e.g. Math.random())
2. Declaration statements - e.g. double i = 0.12654
3. Control flow statements - i.e. if, else, while, etc

i in the second incarnation isn't any of the above, which is why it fails compilation.

Comment: Thanks. What is logic in the first incarnation? Why it should compile and run when we put `Math.random()` in third argument? it is not increment or decrement etc. This statement just returns `double` number. What happens behind..

Comment: Math.random() is an expression statement, so it's allowed after the second semi-colon, but it doesn't change anything - this is the part of a for loop where the variable set in the first statement would usually be modified to give the loop the chance to end - so the loop continues forever.